# OBS (Encoding X264) fails

Tags: streaming, live-recording, x264

Since a few days I have a new computer. Here my specifications:

- GTX 980
- I7 5820k
- Windows 8.1

I'm trying to stream with Open Broadcast Software (OBS), but when I try to preview I already get frame lagg. When I disable encoding while previewing, the frame lagg is gone.

What can I prevent this or what is the problem with this? I talked already with a lot of people about this, but no one really knows a solution. I hope someone here has an idea how to encode x264.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "frame lagg"?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/152502/50186 read also the answer from user *spudone*

Comment: My upload speed is 70mb...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to try:

- Switch to OBS Studio. [OBS classic is no longer supported](https://obsproject.com/download) and has been replaced by the "studio" version.
- Tell your OS to run OBS in ["high priority" mode](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Process-Priorities-in-Windows-Task-Manager).
- Set your encoding preset to a lower quality and/or lower FPS and/or lower definition
- Use your GPU to encode (NVENC). Your CPU will no longer encode your stream and will be able to run other tasks, but it will downgrade the quality of your video.